# Microsoft Translator in Python to translate entire JSON file

Tags: python, translation, microsoft-translator

How to translate entire JSON file having more than 5000 characters, from different language to English using Microsoft Translator. There is a limit of 5000 characters per request, please help me translate the entire file.

I am getting this error:

```
{"error": {"code": 400077, "message": "The maximum request size has been exceeded."}}
```

Comment: You can sub string your text less than 5K character in each request. But because you have sentences you should spilt the text by words like this: text.split()[:500] then attach them. Finally send it

Comment: "attranslate" is a modern tool that solves the problem: https://github.com/fkirc/attranslate Beside of Microsoft, it also works with Google or DeepL.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a free library, Microsoft Translator is not the best option to pick. I suggest you use the [googletrans](https://pypi.org/project/googletrans/) module.
To install simply write `pip install googletrans` from the command line.
Here's an example taken from the documentation:

```
>>> from googletrans import Translator
>>> translator = Translator()
>>> translator.translate('안녕하세요.')
# <Translated src=ko dest=en text=Good evening. pronunciation=Good evening.>
>>> translator.translate('안녕하세요.', dest='ja')
# <Translated src=ko dest=ja text=こんにちは。 pronunciation=Kon'nichiwa.>
>>> translator.translate('veritas lux mea', src='la')
# <Translated src=la dest=en text=The truth is my light pronunciation=The truth is my light>
```

or to translate a list:

```
>>> translations = translator.translate(['The quick brown fox', 'jumps over', 'the lazy dog'], dest='ko')
>>> for translation in translations:
...    print(translation.origin, ' -> ', translation.text)
# The quick brown fox  ->  빠른 갈색 여우
# jumps over  ->  이상 점프
# the lazy dog  ->  게으른 개
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the BreakSentence functionality to break your text to 5000 chars per request. More details on the API can be found here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/cognitive-services/translator/reference/v3-0-break-sentence